# How to reduce image file size after updating it in Nest.JS

Tags: image, nestjs, image-resizing, sharp

I have a problem in my image update routes in Nest.JS , users can upload images with any sizes, and this is very memory consuming ,but I don't want to "limit" image size that can be uploaded, I prefer that I had like a "resize image pipe" that would that automatically for me, I saw something like that in [here](https://dev.to/andercodes/nestjs-creating-a-pipe-to-optimize-uploaded-images-5b3h) but the logic is kinda messy in my opinion,and it does not fit in any way in my code logic,so if anyone has a tip for me I appreciate A LOT

By the way my code logic is like this :

```
@Post('upload/banner/:postId')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './files/posts/banners',
      }),
      fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
    }),
  )
  async uploadAnonymousPostBanner(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @CurrentUserCookie('userId') userId: string,
    @Param('postId') postId: string,
    @Query('postCode') postCode:string
  ) {
    console.log(file);
    const uploadImgFile = await this.postsService.uploadPostBannerImg(
      userId,
      postId,
      file.filename,
      postCode
    );
    return uploadImgFile;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution that i found is to use pipes `PipeTransform` and there you can resize it using sharp or any other package , than u can upload it .
check the nestjs documentaion [nestjs file upload](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) 
and this blog is useful too [Creating a pipe to optimize uploaded images](https://dev.to/andersonjoseph/nestjs-creating-a-pipe-to-optimize-uploaded-images-5b3h)